# how implement api that call some dependent api?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, request, backend

Suppose admin can add api that later user use this ,api but sometime 2 api that admin added could dependent together how to handle in backend that one of response in for example add to header other api and send request and all things shall is dynamic
thx

Answer (score 0):

Check the wiring of the Url starting from the settings of the web application down to the API let them be able to talk to each other if the API is RESTful.